# Could CLR destroy or recycle a blocking thread when garbage collection?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, garbage-collection, clr

I've written a code like this

```
private boid Show(){
  ....
   LogHelper.Info("try lock")
   lock(a){
     LogHelper.Info("get lock")
     .....
    }
   LogHelper.Info("release lock")  
       ....
 }
```

Situation like this, I run a thread through upper code , and it couldn't get the locked resource, so it's being blocked. But I found it that the same thread has been blocked for minutes and then released ?

In my log, show like below

2019-01-24 22:52:45.4663 Info Thread 1 try lock

2019-01-24 23:06:27.7118 Info Thread 1 some other operations

There is no "get lock" and "release lock" in my log, and  do some other operations after locked in Thread 1. So I get a conclusion that CLR recycles my blocking thread.

So does there exist any process to recycle a blocking thread in CLR ?

Comment: What made you think GC got invoked ? It is important that you check your code, especially `LogHelper`, is it not printing certain statements. GC normally has nothing to do with thread recycling it just recovers memory

Comment: @ Mrinal Kamboj   I am sure or I assume that LogHelper is on right status(And it seems work well). So is there any other explanation to this case?